# Syntax for equal character

Tags: html, symbols

As the syntax of the character "<" is &lt, as the syntax of the character ">" is &gt, what is the syntax for the character "=" ; if any exits?

Comment: Are you just looking for a reference of [HTML entities](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references)?

Comment: You _can_ write a plain `=` into HTML, it does not *need* to be encoded like < or >.

Answer (score 0):

The equal sign "=" does not need to be encoded like the < or >.